# Flutter/How to give unique photo for dynamically appending cards

Tags: flutter, dynamic

I am writing a simple application with Flutter and I am new to this field.

I have 3 buttons: Start, Add Photo, and Finish. When the Start button is pressed, the Add Photo and Finish buttons become visible. When I press the Add Photo button, a photo is taken and saved as 'imageFile' with the name 'my_image.jpg'. Then, this file is saved to PhotoData.

When I press the Finish button, dynamic cards are created in my 'GecmisPage' dart file. These cards display information from HistoryData and PhotoData. For example, it stores location, city, district information, and the time. Every time the Finish button is pressed, a new card is created and this process is repeated.

My problem is that I want the photos I take with the Add Photo button to appear in the cards. However, when I take a photo, the same photo appears in all the created cards. It doesn't make sense for the last taken photo to be displayed in a previously created card, does it? Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

The code may seem a bit complex. If you can explain it with a small scenario using these three buttons, that would also do the job for me.

Add Photo Button :

```
class Photo {
  String imagePath;
  DateTime dateTaken;

  Photo({
    required this.imagePath,
    required this.dateTaken,
  });
}
class PhotoData{
  static List<Photo> photos = [];

  static void addPhoto(
      String imagePath,
      DateTime dateTaken,
      ) {
    final photoItem = Photo(
      imagePath: imagePath,
      dateTaken: dateTaken,
    );

    photos.add(photoItem);

  }
}



class CameraButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function(File?) onPictureTaken;
  const CameraButton({Key? key, required this.onPictureTaken}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CameraButtonState createState() => _CameraButtonState();
}
class _CameraButtonState extends State<CameraButton> {
  
  late File? _image = null;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if(pickedFile == null) return;

    setState(() {
      _image = File(pickedFile.path);
    });

    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final imageFile = File('${directory.path}/my_image.jpg');
    await imageFile.writeAsBytes(_image!.readAsBytesSync());

    widget.onPictureTaken(_image!);

  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        _image == null
            ? Text('No image selected.')
            : Image.file(_image!),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: getImage,

          child: Text('Take a Picture'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

GecmisPage  :

```
Container(
                            color: Constant.tema13,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: PhotoData.photos.length,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                final photo = PhotoData.photos[index];
                                return ListTile(
                                  leading: Image.file(File(photo.imagePath)),

                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          )
```

Geçmiş Page Scaffold :

```
    body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: HistoryData.history.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  width: screenWidth/4,
                  height: screenHeight/10,
                  child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    ),
                    color: Color(0xFFBCF6E7),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        onCardTap(
                          index,
                          HistoryData.history[index].date as String,
                          HistoryData.history[index].time,
                        );
                      },
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0,),
                            child: Image.asset("assets/images/loc.png", height: 30, width: 30,),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:20),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text("Başlangıç Yeri", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
                                Text("${HistoryData.history[index].city}" + " / " + "${HistoryData.history[index].district}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),

                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:30.0),
                            child:
                            Text("${HistoryData.history[index].date}\n${HistoryData.history[index].time}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                            child: Checkbox(
                              activeColor: Constant.darkgrey,
                              checkColor: Constant.green,
                              value: _selectedList[index],
                              onChanged: (bool? newValue) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _selectedList[index] = newValue!;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
```

Also, when a card is clicked here, a page is opened with a MaterialPageRoute, and the photos list is called with the container below on this page.

```
    Container(
                                color: Constant.opacgrey,
                            child: BlocBuilder<PhotosCubit, PhotosState>(
                              builder: (context, state) {
                                return ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemCount: state.photos.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                    final photo = state.photos[index];
                                    return ListTile(
                                      leading: Image.file(File(photo.imagePath)),
                                    );
                                  },
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
```

I'm not entirely sure, but I think I might be having issues because the same page is being opened with a MaterialPageRoute every time a card is clicked.

Comment: How are you accessing `List<Photo>` inside `GecmisPage`?

Comment: @Soliev I followed your instructions exactly, but my problem still persists. All the photos in the 'photos' list are shown on every card created on the 'Geçmiş' page. Each card represents travel data for me. The 'Start' button starts the journey, and the 'End' button ends it. When I press the 'Start' button, the 'Add Photo' button becomes active. If I add a photo with this button, only the photos added for that trip should be shown on the card created on the 'Geçmiş' page. Could the error possibly occur while creating the cards on the 'Geçmiş' page? I've editing my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some state management to handle this easily rather than using static variables and methods from you `PhotoData` class;

Example:

```
class PhotosState extends Equatable {
  const PhotosState({this.photos = const []});

  final List<Photo> photos;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [photos];
}

class PhotosCubit extends Cubit<PhotosState> {
  PhotosCubit() : super(const PhotosState());

  void addPhoto(
    String imagePath,
    DateTime dateTaken,
  ) {
    final photo = Photo(imagePath: imagePath, dateTaken: dateTaken);
    emit(
      PhotosState(
        photos: List.of(state.photos)..add(photo),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Don't forget to change `onPictureTaken` callback when you use `CameraButton`

```
            CameraButton(
              onPictureTaken: (file) {
                context
                    .read<PhotosCubit>()
                    .addPhoto(file!.path, DateTime.now());
              },
            ),
```

Finally you can use `BlocBuilder` to update your UI with newly added `Photo`.

```
 return Container(
      child: BlocBuilder<PhotosCubit, PhotosState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: state.photos.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final photo = state.photos[index];
              return ListTile(
                leading: Image.file(File(photo.imagePath)),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I followed your instructions exactly, but my problem still persists. All the photos in the 'photos' list are shown on every card created on the 'Geçmiş' page. Each card represents travel data for me. The 'Start' button starts the journey, and the 'End' button ends it. When I press the 'Start' button, the 'Add Photo' button becomes active. If I add a photo with this button, only the photos added for that trip should be shown on the card created on the 'Geçmiş' page. Could the error possibly occur while creating the cards on the 'Geçmiş' page? I've editing my question